# How to delete aws snapshots automatically after a retention period?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, volume, snapshot

I have 25k + snapshots in my account and wanted them to be deleted. I will do that. 
But henceforth, I can't do it manually. So have to set a retention period (eg: 10 days) and want them deleted automatically after the retention period with the script.

Do some one have script to do that?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried and have a script to delete the snapshots that are 30 days old. But need a script to delete automatically after a retention period.

The snapshots should be deleted after a retention period.

Comment: One approach is a Lambda function that's invoked from a CloudWatch Events scheduled event. Does this work for you?

Comment: Can You please provide me a link or some script to perform it?

Comment: You say: " have tried and have a script to delete the snapshots that are 30 days old. But need a script to delete automatically after a retention period." Why does the script that deletes snapshots after 30 days not satisfy your requirement?

Comment: @John, 30 days script deletes the old snapshots so far. from now, I have do it automatically after the retention period.

Comment: What do you mean by "retention period"? Can't you just change the script to a different number of days?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/whatisbackup.html):

> AWS Backup is a fully managed backup service that makes it easy to centralize and automate the backup of data across AWS services in the cloud and on premises. Using AWS Backup, you can centrally configure backup policies and monitor backup activity for your AWS resources. AWS Backup automates and consolidates backup tasks that were previously performed service-by-service, removing the need to create custom scripts and manual processes. With just a few clicks on the AWS Backup console, you can create backup policies that automate backup schedules and **retention management**.

See also [Automating the Amazon EBS Snapshot Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html):

> You can use Amazon Data Lifecycle Manager (Amazon DLM) to automate the creation, retention, and deletion of snapshots taken to back up your Amazon EBS volumes.

Comment: Amazon DLM, Yes I checked. But it deleted the snapshots based on the number of snapshots and not on the retention period.

Comment: What i feel is a script to do this will be better, as I can run the script daily .

Answer (score 0):

There is also available solution from Amazon directly:

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/ops-automator/

This solution includes actions to automatically create, copy and delete EBS snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

To delete these snapshots you can simply use a bash script which will fetch all the snapshot ids older than 10  days and then can delete them using AWS CLI command.

to find all the snapshots created before a particular timestamp (say some date):

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner self --output json | jq '.Snapshots[] | select(.StartTime > "2019-12-18")' > snap_list.txt
```

use for loop to delete all the snapshots from the list generated one by one.

```
for snap_id in `cat snap_list.txt`
do
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $snap_id
done
```

or you can simply use the snapshot retention period in AWS for snapshot automatic deletion in future

Comment: The `jq` filter as written will output JSON into the resulting file. You need to add another filter to extract just the desired `.SnapshotId` field, and you'd probably want to pipe that into `sed` to strip the double quotes. I believe the `aws` command also requires a region. And finally, flip the greater/less if you want to remove *older* snapshots.

    `aws ec2 describe-snapshots --region='region-name' --owner self --output json | jq '.Snapshots[] | select(.StartTime < "2021-04-27") | .SnapshotId' | sed 's/"//g' > snap_list.txt`

Comment: @BrianDunne this is correct, though `--region` is not required (assuming if its set in your AWS profile

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like the [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/whatisbackup.html) or [Lifecycle Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html) to do this in an automated manner when you're creating new snapshots but if you need to deal with old snapshots in an existing count which wasn't using that sort of thing, here's how you can do it.

I would strongly recommend configuring [Recycling Bin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recycle-bin.html) before doing this, just in case you make a mistake.

Note that the examples below use a JMESPath query to filter out anything tagged by AWS Backup.

1. Query for old snapshots, relying on the `date` CLI utility to calculate one month before the current date in this example:

```bash
$ aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner self --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime <= `'$(date -v -1m -I)'` && !contains(Tags[].Key, `aws:backup:source-resource`)]'
```

2. After you've reviewed the results and confirmed that these really should be deleted:

```bash
$ aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner self --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime <= `'$(date -v -1m -I)'` && !contains(Tags[].Key, `aws:backup:source-resource`)].[SnapshotId]' --output=text | xargs -P32 -L1 -p aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id
```

Note the `-p` in there to prompt you for confirmation. Remove that when you're absolutely certain that you really want to delete things.